# How to check if there is an image present in the image view?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I am new to iPhone development. I want to check for a condition whether the image is present in the image view? I have created a image view such as

```
UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 6.0f,50.0f, 50.0f)];
```

How to check whether the image is present in the image view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (subView.image != nil)
   // image is present
else
   // image missing
```